# Ways to incorporate functions into source code

Tags: c++, header-files

Recently I started to develop a program, and let's just say that it uses a ton of functions (global), and I started off having all the functions in the main source code, but then I remembered that your primary code should be as clean as possible. I then started making header files, and having the function bodies defined in those header files, and then including these header files by means of

```
#include "headerFileName.h"
```

I wanted to know if there is a better way to do this, or is this even recommended as compared to having all the definitions in the primary source code file.

Comment: You should probably use classes instead of global functions. That would simplify your life a lot.

Comment: Don't just clutter up a file with methods. Couldn't these methods belong to a class like `utilities` or similar? Anyway, you're correct, don't have a main file with all your global functions in it.

Comment: Do you use the same set of functions for most of your programs?

Comment: @PawełStawarz I started off using classes, but then I realized to call the functions I'd have to create objects of the class, which in turn didn't fit my plan, so I had to resort to functions.

Comment: @awesomeyi From what it looks, I'll be having a lot of functions, which will be doing similar things, but they all will serve a purpose.. for example to I have multiple "report" functions that log events, but at the moment I have different "report" functions for different events. In the future I might make it into one function.

Comment: @MayurMohan you don't have to do that if you use `static` member functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you actually want to do is separate the *declaration* of your functions from their *definition*. A function declaration looks like this:

```
return_type function_name(function arguments...);
```

and says to the compiler that this function exists, takes these kinds of arguments, but does not tell the compiler how the function is implemented. You put these declarations in header files, and anyone who includes the header can use the function (without knowing its definition).

In a *separate .cpp file*, you put the *definition* of the function, which looks like

```
return_type function_name(function arguments...) {
    /* code */
}
```

This is the real implementation. What you are doing is separating "interface" (declarations) from "implementation" (definitions).

Crucially, this means that the interface specifies only what you can do, not how it is done under the covers. This ensures that other functions that call the interface do not have to worry (or know) about the implementation. If you code to this standard, your program will be more modular, simpler to maintain, and a lot easier to work with and reason about.

Comment: Oh I see. And then the .cpp file is also included in the main source code right? Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: @MayurMohan: No, you compile `.cpp` files alongside your other source files, and *link* them together at the end. For example, `g++ main.cpp utils.cpp myclass.cpp -o myprog`, if you were using the command-line G++ compiler. In an IDE, you would add your other `.cpp` files as extra source files.